# How to Upload Images compressed on Server in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload, server

I have been trying to compress image while uploading with the following code but unable to figure out where to implement compression code in it.Kindly Help.

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d:h:i:s');

if($_FILES['file1']['name']!="")
    {
        $sql_banner_id = "SELECT MAX(id) from autosale";
        $result_banner_id = mysql_query($sql_banner_id);
        $rs_banner_id = mysql_fetch_array($result_banner_id);
        if($rs_banner_id[0]==0)
        {
            $banner_id  = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $banner_id = $rs_banner_id[0]+1;
        }
        $control_name = "file1";
        $target = "autosale_image";
        $new_name = "sale".$banner_id;
        $path = upload_all_photo($control_name, $target, $new_name, 80);
        $control_name = "file2";
        $target = "autosale_image";
        $new_name = "sale1".$banner_id;
        $path1 = upload_all_photo($control_name, $target, $new_name, 80);
    }
    $sql_add_directory = "INSERT INTO autosale
    (
        name , email , m_address, contact , city , country, c_companyname, model,  variant, km, description, price, image_path, image_path1, timestamp 
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        '$name', '$emailid', '$address', '$mobile', '$city',  '$country', '$carmake', '$car_model','$variant', '$km', '$description', '$price', '$path', '$path1', '$timestamp'
    )";
    //echo $sql_add_directory;
    $result_add_directory = mysql_query($sql_add_directory) or die("error".mysql_error());
    //header("location:thanks_subscription.php"); // redirect for normal user
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='thanks_autosale.php';</script>";
```

Comment: there is no code here that deals with compression of images

Comment: What do you mean by compressing an image? Do you want to change its resolution or compress the file so that it takes less space? Most image formats already use compression and further compressing them usually does not make the file any smaller. If you want to scale it in php, you will need to load it and scale it using some function such as imagescale(), but it may well be better to use some external utility for this purpose.